# is it possible to run a flutter mobile app in the browser?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and I think that the android emulator uses too much Resources so I think I can develop my app and run it in the browser as if it was a flutter web app .
My question is will it affect the performance of my app or make the apk size bigger ? or is there any differences in development between flutter web and flutter mobile ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can build your flutter for web and it would look like mobile app if you develop it in such way, and web version is not using APK at all.
But not all functionality is supported in web at the moment (it's still in beta, but mostly everything you need you will find) and there is still lot of libraries that developed mainly for mobile platform without web support.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop flutter web for running web,
but you can not run flutter app(apk) on web.
For more info of flutter web check [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web).